# prints the sum of the numbers 1 to n in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

**GOAL:**
Write a program that asks the user for a number `n` and prints the sum
of the numbers 1 to n.  The program keeps asking for a number until
the user enters 0.

```
expected output:
enter an integer number (0 to end): 5
1+2+3+4+5 = 15
```

I am able to solve the second problem which is until the user enters 0.
the problem I'm having is printing the numbers in a loop.

```
1+2+3+4+5 = 15
```

I am thinking maybe if I use a loop within a loop I can accomplish this. This is my current code.I've seen other questions answer this programming question but I wanna know how to specifically print the numbers leading up to the number I entered

```
num = int(input( "enter a integer: " ))
sum_num =0

if num != 0:
   for i in range(1, num+1): 
       sum_num += i
       print(sum_num)
else:
     exit()
```

Comment: What you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this matches what you want:

```
while True:
  output = ""
  num = int(input("enter a integer: "))

  if num == 0:
    exit()

  for i in range(1, num+1):
    output += "{}".format(i)
    if i != num:
      output += "+"
  output += " = {}".format(sum(range(num+1)))
  print (output)
```

This prints out the sum of integers and then the answer, then waits for the next input. Example output:

```
$ python test.py
enter a integer: 5
1+2+3+4+5 = 15
enter a integer: 4
1+2+3+4 = 10
enter a integer: 3
1+2+3 = 6
enter a integer: 2
1+2 = 3
enter a integer: 1
1 = 1
enter a integer: 0
 = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Several issues with your code:

1. Your `while` loop will never end. Its intended purpose is not clear.
2. You are summing 1 instead of `i` each time in your loop.
3. Your `print` statement only occurs at the end. You can include it within your loop.
4. In Python, `range(n)` excludes *n*, so use `range(n + 1)` instead.
5. You do not need to convert integers to string in order to `print` them.

Putting this all together:

```
num = int(input( "enter a integer: " ))
sum_num = 0

for i in range(1, num+1): 
    sum_num += i
    print(sum_num)

enter a integer: 5
1
3
6
10
15
```

Comment: why do we use +1 on the second part of the range?

Comment: `range(a)` goes from `0` to `a-1` (it's non-inclusive on the right hand side), but you want to *include* `a`, so you have to add 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
num=int(input("Enter the Number " ))
sum=0

for i in range(1, num + 1):
        sum = sum+ i
print(sum)
```

`Enter the Number 9
45`

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input("enter the no. : "))
sum = 0
for i in range(1,n+1):
    if(i<n):
        print(i,"+", end=" ")
    else:
        print(i,end=" ")
    sum = sum + i
print("=",sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```py
def cumsum(n: int) -> int:
    """Helper function to calculate cumulative sum"""                                                                                
    return sum(range(n))                                                                                                                                                                                        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    """Main entry point"""
                                                   
    while n := int(input("Number: ")):                                                                  
        print(cumsum(n))
```

- `cumsum` calculates the cumulative sum
- `__name__ == "__main__"` is python-specific boilerplate
- `n :=`  is the "walrus-operator", meaning it assigns to n at the point it's evaluating the `input`. The `while` loop terminates at 0 simply because 0 is "falsy".

Without the boilerplate code, in 2 lines:

```py
while n := int(input("Number: ")):
    print(sum(range(n)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int (input (''))
print(n*(n+1)//2)
```

Answer (score -2):

n*(n+1)/2

"zBody zmust zbe zat zleast z30 zcharacters; zyou zentered z9 z..."

Comment: Instead of adding nonsense padding, you could have added an explanation as to why this is the correct answer.

Answer (score -2):

```
num = int(input())  
total = num  
for x in range(num):  
    total += x  
print(total)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).